# Unable to load embedding model with langchain.embeddings after installing vLLM

Tags: langchain, large-language-model, llama-index

I am currently using a RAG pipeline with an LLM model from HuggingFace, along with document ingestion and retrieval powered by LLamaIndex. I've noticed that incorporating vLLM into my pipeline could enhance throughput and reduce response time.

While testing a basic version of the vLLM pipeline with only the LLM model from HuggingFace, everything worked smoothly. However, I encountered errors when attempting to integrate an embedding model when it worked fine before. I have also re-installed langchain, llama-index, and any transformers library after installing vLLM, but does not fix the issue.

**Library and versions used:**

```
!pip install -q langchain==0.1.9 llama-index==0.10.13.post1 llama-index-llms-langchain==0.1.3 llama-index-embeddings-langchain==0.1.2 pymupdf==1.23.25 pypdf==4.0.2 sentence_transformers==2.4.0 accelerate==0.27.2 bitsandbytes==0.42.0
!pip install -q vllm==0.3.3
```

**Source code**

```
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from llama_index.embeddings.langchain import LangchainEmbedding

model_name = "hkunlp/instructor-xl"
lc_embed_model = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name=model_name)
embed_model = LangchainEmbedding(lc_embed_model)
```

**Snippet of error:**

```
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.pipelines because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/transformer_engine_extensions.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5torch3jit17parseSchemaOrNameERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```